# MVC type for the zend framewok

Tags: model-view-controller, zend-framework

I did some research about MVC, and found out that there are two types of MVC:

- Active MVC: The active MVC makes the model independent of the controller, in this case the model prevents directly the view of the change.
- Passive MVC: In passive MVC only the controller can manipulates the model. It manage also the synchronization between view and model.

What type of MVC is the Zend framework using?

Comment: passive i would say controller sends data from model to view

Comment: yes that's what I mean, but what is the type used by the zend framework ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you must understand here is that the Active vs Passive are concepts.

The Zend Framework won't force you into one of both.  It is your role, as a developer, to follow the concept that fits your needs.  I personally use a passive approach with Zend Framework.

I would say that if you use the Zend Framework to build an application using the information found in the "Quickstart with Zend Framework" on their website, they are showing a **Passive MVC**.

See their tutorial here: http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/learning.quickstart.intro.html

(but you can also see in the schema that the Model can/could talk to the View too... which could be transformed in the Active MVC if you want.)

The controller calls the model and then pass the received data to the view.  That said, it doesn't mean you can't code differently.  It is possible to call the view from the model if you want.

Sometimes, people think they absolutely have to create a MVC application if they want to use the Zend Framework.  That is wrong!  If you want to use only `Zend_Date` in your project because you like the way ZF can manipulate dates, you can.  As you can see, there is no MVC involved and you are using the Zend Framework.